# Adicionar valores nas células no StringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Gostaria que quando clicasse em uma célula do `StringGrid` eu pudesse adicionar um numero e apertando pro lado ele fosse pulando de célula em célula, bem parecido com o `excel`, é possível fazer isso com esse componente?

Já tentei usar o `keypress`, mas não funciona muito bem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, você deve habilitar a opção *goEditing* em *Options* do StringGrid; Depois, no evento onKeyDown, adicione o código (Com **ENTER**):

```
if key = 13 then
  begin
    if StringGrid.Col < (StringGrid.ColCount - 1) then StringGrid.Col := StringGrid.Col + 1
    else
      if StringGrid.Row < (StringGrid.RowCount -1) then
        begin
          StringGrid.Col:= StringGrid.FixedCols;
          if StringGrid.Row < (StringGrid.RowCount -1) then StringGrid.Row := StringGrid.Row + 1
        end
      else Perform(WM_NEXTDLGCTL,0,0);
  end;
```

Para fazer com as teclas de direção, use os seus códigos ASC II:

> 37 (seta para esquerda)
>   38 (seta para cima)
>   39 (seta para direita)
>   40 (seta para baixo)

Claro que para usar com as teclas de direção, uma lógica aprimorada terá de ser aplicada, acima está apenas o caminho das pedras.